# building an existing react native application issue (cocoapods)

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, mobile, cocoapods

I am trying to build a react native application. I am running into the issue bellow:

*I am working with existing react native project*

```
Could not find cocoapods-core-1.8.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Could not find cocoapods-core-1.8.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

what code is sh file is:

```
npm install

cd ios
bundle exec pod repo update
bundle exec pod install
cd ..
```

I already uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods

What else can i do?

Comment: Maybe try to install the latest cocoapods version ..?

Comment: Thank, i am too use to conda, but i install specifici version

Answer (score 0):

As the error comment said:

Run `bundle install`

You are using `bundler`, you need to install the ruby dependencies before to run any `bundle exec` command.